# How do I extract value from a text file in Makefile?

Tags: makefile

Here's the code snippet from my Makefile:

```
%/foo: %/bar.yaml
    $(BINARY) generate -g go \
        --package-name {COOL_VALUE}
# COOL_VALUE should be the value for a unique `x-cool-value` key from `bar.yaml`.
```

E.g., here's `bar.yaml`:

```
abc:
  xyz: Hi StackOverflow!
  x-cool-value: v1
```

and I'd like to extract `v1` value.

E.g.,

```
make foo1/foo2/foo
> ./binary generate -g go \
   --package-name v1
# since foo1/foo2/foo/bar.yaml had a `v1` value for `abc.x-cool-value` key.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do things like that using makefile syntax (at least it's not worth it).  Figure out how to do it using a shell command, then put that shell command in your makefile recipe.

For example:

```
$ sed -n 's/^ *x-cool-value: *//p' foo1/foo2/foo/bar.yaml
v1
```

So, in your makefile:

```
%/foo: %/bar.yaml
        $(BINARY) generate -g go \
            --package-name $$(sed -n 's/^ *x-cool-value: *//p' $<)
```

Or you can try to find some command-line tool that parses YAML and lets you query things; there probably is one.

Comment: what if I wanna match more complex example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68186777/how-can-i-use-sed-to-extract-a-value-from-a-text-file?