# How can I create a simple regexp for sed?

Tags: shell, sed, replace

Here's a text file #1 I've got:

```
abc:
  xyz: Hi StackOverflow!
  x-cool-value: v5
```

and here's another one:

```
abc:
  xyz: Hi StackOverflow!
  x-cool-value: foobar/v7
```

so for the first file I'd like to extract `v5` and for #2: `v7`. `x-cool-value` is always a constant / present in the input text files.

I came up with:

```
$ sed -n 's/^ *x-cool-value: *//p' foo.yaml
# return either `v2` or `foobar/v7`
```

but not sure how to make it work for both test files.

Comment: If this is YAML, use a YAML parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, sure that won't work.  By adding `: *` you're just saying "a colon followed by zero or more spaces".  That works fine if what you want is the entire line after the spaces.  But if you want to skip more than spaces you have to make your regular expression match the stuff you want to skip.

It seems, although you didn't actually define it, that you want to skip all spaces *PLUS* all characters up to and including a final `/`, if one exists.  Another way to interpret what you want is, all characters up to and including the *first* `/` but since you didn't say I chose to implement the former.

That can be done something like this:

```
sed -n 's,^ *x-cool-value: *\(.*/\)*,,p' foo.yaml
```

I changed the regular expression delimiter from `/` to `,` here but you can choose whatever you like: I didn't want to use `/` since that appears in the regular expression.

The extra bit `\(.*/\)*` means, match a group of characters that ends with a `/`, zero or more times.

You would be well-advised to go find a book or a website that gives you some instruction on regular expressions.  They're extremely useful and an absolute requirement for anyone wanting to do any sort of non-trivial scripting in POSIX systems like Linux and MacOS.